# Datagridview selections with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Help pls! I want to automatically select all the rows that has the same value in a particular cell of every rows when the user manually select or click on a particular row. am using vb.net. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing a solution while the OP has made no effort to resolve it by itself

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is not clear enough, you can try:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then
        If DataGridView1.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            findOnGridview(DataGridView1, DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(), DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


    Private Sub findOnGridview(g As DataGridView, s As String, c As Integer)
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To g.Rows.Count - 1
        If g.Rows(i).Cells(c).Value = s Then
            g.Rows(i).Cells(c).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Else
            g.Rows(i).Cells(c).Style.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```